# Make Brave default browser 22.04.03 LTS

Tags: firefox, browser, brave

I have followed the suggestions on this page to no avail.  Firefox remains default browser and when I open Firefox settings it indicates it is default browser and will not allow me to uncheck it.  Any suggestions? thanx